# C# - Drawing top image over background image (alpha channel) - WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, image, alpha-transparency

I've got this topimage with alpha channel in it and I need to put this image over another background image, while the alpha channel from the top image stays intact obviously.

Now I've seen some tutorials with Canvas, but my project doesn't seem to recognize Canvas.

Anyone got an idea why I cant use Canvas or how to put those 2 images over each other?

Comment: WPF or WinForms? I assume you didn't include the needed references. What does "doesn't seem to recognize" exactly mean? Could you please post the code and the error message?

Comment: @Tigran I don't really know, saw some tutorials about it but I think it is Java though.

Comment: @Vlad WinForms, later just an image for asp

Comment: @Julian: in WinForms, as is, you don't have Canvas concept. Why do not just use DrawImage? Did you try it?

Comment: @Tigran, yes I did, but the alpha channel didn't work so I only saw the top image.

Comment: @Julian: the tutorials with Canvas are about WPF framework. Canvas is a tool for WPF to emulate the behaviour of WinForms :-)

Comment: @Vlad Hmm, but I use WinForm and later just saving it as image and showing it in asp.net. Thanks for telling me though.

Comment: @Julian: Could be that saying "alpha channel" you mean transparent regions on image or semitransparent, "smoke" like effect?

Comment: @Tigran Full transparent parts of the image made in Photoshop.

Comment: @Julian: try out my answer, if you didn't already and let me know if it works. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I will try to answer: after loading the image, like this more or less, pseudocode:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("MyCooolSemiTransparentImage.png"); 
bmp.MakeTransparent(colorHaveToBeRenderedTransparent);
```

colorHaveToBeRenderedTransparent is a color wich results **non** transparent after loading it into `Bitmap`  object.

**EDIT**

if alphachannel is ok, here is a simple tutorial how to draw in image on WinForms:

[msdn: DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f9s3at1.aspx)

Call method provided in yuor forms OnPaint override and you will get what you want.

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks Tigran, but I have no "colorHaveToBeRenderedTransparent, because that part is already alphachannel.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter. Though I tried it with normal painting but then the alphachannel doesn't work out and just covers the background image. Anyway I'll try again and look at my image again if you are certain it should work. Thanks!

Comment: Saying "cover" I understand that there is not more transparent color on it. Correct ? If so, get exact value of that color that have to be transparent and use it in colorHaveToBeRenderedTransparent variable.