# Transparent images not showing properly

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

When I am trying to load transparent images on the panel with graphics on it before:
[image]

This is what I get after:

[image]

Code on how I load my image:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\Some_Path\image.jpg");
this.Image = bmp;
```

Every time I am pressing the button, this is called:

```
this.panel2.Controls.Add(obj_withImage)
```

How should I load them in order to be shown?

Comment: Oh boy, here come the downvotes.

Comment: Ehm, why? I mean I've tried so many things

Comment: Not from me, just because people on this site are annoying.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6746250/1997232) a duplicate question?

Comment: MakeTransparent() doesnt work

Comment: @Sinatr thanks a lot.
I honestly tried MakeTransparent, but in this answer it is shown differently

Comment: Not sure just what you are doing. If the images are in controls nested in the panels as your code looks like, then in should work, Otoh you write _panel with graphics on it_ but also: `this.Image = bmp;` now which?  is the panel or the form holding the staff image? - In any case the question is cerainly not a dußlicate of the link. Probably of some others, though..

Comment: Actually your screenshot makes no sense unless you have actually used non-tranparent images. Use proper images as [for example these](http://images.google.de/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F3%2F3d%2FNotes.svg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFile%3ANotes.svg&h=359&w=971&tbnid=B_xaNACCoSP9aM%3A&docid=PVjU10n_RvnniM&ei=ThxrVuukAsP9ywPn1ZG4BQ&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=918&page=1&start=0&ndsp=15&ved=0ahUKEwjrg5eFvtTJAhXD_nIKHedqBFcQrQMIXzAO) and do keep them in PNG format which will allow for transparency!!